# Display a map and highlight certain areas

Tags: jquery, google-maps, maps

My question is essentially this one [Display a map and highlight certain countries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12696526/display-a-map-and-highlight-certain-countries) but what I need to draw in the map are not countries or states but cities or regions inside a city like a neighborhood or a block.

Is that possible to be done with Google geochart or other tool that works through jquery/js over google maps?

Comment: http://www.dyngeometry.com/web/Address.aspx - here is an example of it being done - it's a soap service , not what you asked for , but I figured it might help still

Comment: you basically would need a **`kml`** overlay. Do some research in that regard

Comment: @ScottSelby looks like it is not granular enough. The deepest I can get is ZIP code. Well, I believe nothing can go further.

Comment: What country? Zillow has some ["neighborhood" polygons available for the US](http://www.zillow.com/howto/api/neighborhood-boundaries.htm) (as zipped shapefiles).

Comment: As much countries as possible, mainly turistic contries like West Europe, east Asia, South America, Caribe and this way on