# Google Maps Region and Countries polygon

Tags: ios, google-maps

This must be quite a simple question, but unable to find any answer.

I wish to show regions given a region name, like

if the input is NewYork State, then i wish to show the NewYork state with one colour initially . Then when the user zooms in, show different districts or significant places or regions with other distinct colors and so on.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12696526/display-a-map-and-highlight-certain-countries this may be of help it's for countries but you could fork it.

Answer (score 0):

You need a a `GMSPolygon`

for that you need a `GMSPath` that is basically a list of coordinates that make up the frame. You can get the list of coordinates for a given region via some web services like google or openstreetmaps